# If loop with workday() vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with this sequence of if statements.  The error I'm getting is: Object required.  I'm just going to give the relevant area of the code, please assume all variables are properly defined.

```
For i = 6 To LastRow
    If Cell.Value("$I" & i) = "" Then
        Cell.Value("$I" & i) = Format(Now(), "MMM-DD-YYYY")
    ElseIf Cell.Value("$N" & i) = "" Then
        Cell.Value("$I" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay("$J" & i + "$L" & i - 1, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

I'm having trouble getting the workday function to work properly.  Any ideas?

Comment: `Cell.Value("$I" & i)` is your problem, what do you think you are doing with that statement.

Comment: I think I'm referencing the value of a cell at range I6, then I7 and so on until I hit the value associated with LastRow.  Is this not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to add some fixes:

```
For i = 6 To LastRow
    If Cells( i, "I").Value = "" Then
        Cells( i, "I").Value = Format(Now(), "MMM-DD-YYYY")
    ElseIf Cells( i, "N").Value = "" Then
        Cells( i, "I").Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Cells(i, "J").Value, 1), "MMM-DD-YYYY")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Yeah this loop calculates the next day someone needs to be contacted.  In the part that you're confused about, it looks in a cell ("N") to see if there's a date of contact there and, if there isn't, it calculates what the next date of contact should be using a number of workdays past the last day of successful contact (stored in J).  It's hard to describe without showing you, but hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You can tell I'm used to doing in cell references on a worksheet instead of formatting things properly in VBA.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DustinBurns So the output of the lookup if N&i = "" should be displayed in column N or I?  I believe I've got you squared away, atm... added in formatting so the serial date doesn't show up.  For WorkDay() you will have a start date then an end date... if the end date is "5", then it will add 5 workdays to the start date.

Comment: In column I.  Yes you've answered the question wonderfully, thank you :)